# Adding methods to a Prototype vs existing Prototype Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

What is difference between adding method to a Prototype and existing prototype in Javascript?

```
function Person(fname, lname) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}
Person.prototype.name = function() {
    return this.fname + this.lname;
}
```

and

```
function Person(fname, lname) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;

    this.name = function() {
        return this.fname 
    }
}
```

result is same.